# Google App Engine - Is there a way to get some sort of current time that would be consistent across instances of my app

Tags: google-app-engine

If I call `new Date()` it will get the current time for the machine my app is running on.

I'm assuming that the machines on the Google App Engine do not all have their time synchronized.

Is there a way to get a time that would be consistent across instances of my app that may be running on different machines?

Comment: App Engine instances should be synchronized. Have you found this not to be the case? Are you just trying to store a datetime consistently across all entities?

Comment: @jason just trying to store a datetime consistently in MemCache, I haven't found a problem with datetimes out of sync, but I'm wondering if they could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Machines are NTP synchronized, so they will be within a few milliseconds of each other, but there's no way to get a global monotonic counter on App Engine. This is because the only way to do so requires a single authority, and is thus not a scalable solution.